AttributeError: module 'zpl2' has no attribute 'BARCODE_CODE_11'
I'm getting this error on zpl2 library when i run my python project
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 205, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 193, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/jnunes/Documents/dsswebv11/odoo/service/server.py", line 250, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/home/jnunes/Documents/dsswebv11/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 166, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/jnunes/Documents/dsswebv11/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 154, in application_unproxied
    result = handler(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/jnunes/Documents/dsswebv11/odoo/http.py", line 1315, in __call__
    self.load_addons()
  File "/home/jnunes/Documents/dsswebv11/odoo/http.py", line 1347, in load_addons
    m = __import__('odoo.addons.' + module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
    
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
    
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
    
  File "/home/jnunes/Documents/dsswebv11/odoo/modules/module.py", line 82, in load_module
    exec(open(modfile, 'rb').read(), new_mod.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
    
  File "/home/jnunes/Documents/dsswebv11/dss/printer_zpl2/models/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import printing_label_zpl2_component
  File "/home/jnunes/Documents/dsswebv11/dss/printer_zpl2/models/printing_label_zpl2_component.py", line 27, in <module>
    class PrintingLabelZpl2Component(models.Model):
  File "/home/jnunes/Documents/dsswebv11/dss/printer_zpl2/models/printing_label_zpl2_component.py", line 50, in PrintingLabelZpl2Component
    (zpl2.BARCODE_CODE_11, 'Code 11'),

Python version: 3.5.6
zpl2 version: 1.2.1
I try to install:
sudo pip3 install zpl2
expected:
code running

Do you perhaps have another file named zpl2.py somewhere?  The simplest explanation is that your import zpl2 is finding something other than the module you installed.

I don't know if there is a better way but i found a solution:
I copy the zpl2 source code and substitute the code installed on my machine for it.
